# Microsoft Graph API UnkownError

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What am I doing wrong? I want to list the files in the root of my OneDrive. But I always get a **401 Unauthorized**.

I used Fiddler to track the requests and requesting the OAuth token seems to work fine. But when I try to request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children I get Unauthorized as response with the code **UnknownError**

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient()
    {
        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        };


        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CLIENT_ID)
                                                .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.PersonalMicrosoftAccount)
                                                .WithClientSecret(SECRET)
                                                .Build();

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
            new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                    var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

                    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
            );

        return graphServiceClient;
    }

var drive = GraphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.
Request().
GetAsync();
```

FYI: I am using .NET MVC 5 and I want to access my **personal** onedrive without user interaction. I seem to be a bit lost with what flow I should use for this.

Comment: I would check the token in https://jwt.ms to see whether you have the necessary permission/roles/scopes or not.

Comment: What kind of type is your application? Is it a web app or console app?

Comment: It is .NET MVC application (.NET Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `/me/drive/root/children` endpoint, so you should use a user token rather than application token.

You are using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) with:

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CLIENT_ID)
              .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.PersonalMicrosoftAccount)
              .WithClientSecret(SECRET)
              .Build();
```

Here you need to add `.WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)`. See sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider).

And you should not use `AcquireTokenForClient` method here because it is requiring an application token with [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

If you are trying to call Microsoft Graph in a .net core MVC, please refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3).

Acquire the access token:

```
string token = await _tokenAcquisition
    .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes);
```

If your application is .net MVC, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/5-exercise-add-auth).

```
var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                .Build();

            string message;
            string debug;

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                message = "Access token retrieved.";
                debug = result.AccessToken;
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

There are 2 scenes that we could connect to OneDrive without any further human interaction.

1. Use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), which allow us to call Microsoft Graph with an **application token**. You need to add **Application Permission** into your Azure AD app. You should choose [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) and use  `GraphClient.Users["{userId or UPN}"].Drive.Root.Children` instead of `GraphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children` because there is no user(`/me`) in this case.

[image]

Corresponding code:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var children = await graphClient.Users["{userId or UPN}"].Drive.Root.Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

2. If you want to use `GraphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children` but don't want sign-in interactively, you could choose [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider), which uses [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). This scene also uses **user token** rather than application token.

Please note that:

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
> more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
> requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
> risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
> flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

You need to add **Delegated Permission** in this case.

[image]

Corresponding code:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

var email = "{your username}";
var str = "{your password}";
var password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in str) password.AppendChar(c);

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var children= await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                .GetAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Unfortunately, both Client Credential flow and ROPC(Resource Owner Password Credentials) flow don't support personal accounts. For personal accounts, you have to use auth code flow I mentioned at the beginning and it requires you to **sign-in interactively**. In summary, it's impossible to access personal Onedrive without any further human interaction.

Comment: what is the redirect uri for? I simply want to store the client secret and connect to OneDrive without any further human interaction.

Comment: @stickfigure4 See the **UPDATE** in my answer.

Comment: I tried the first option but with no success.. if I try to fetch the Users for example I get "Authorization_RequestDenied". But if I understand correctly isn't this because this doesn't work for personal accounts?

Comment: @stickfigure4 Unfortunately, Both client credential flow and ROPC(Resource Owner Password Credentials) flow don't support personal accounts. For personal accounts, you have to use auth code flow I mentioned at the beginning and it requires you to **sign-in interactively**. In summary, it's impossible to access personal onedrive without any further human interaction. Have updated it in my answer. If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Would there be any other alternative to make it possible?

Comment: @stickfigure4 We can only access the personal OneDrive with interaction. I'm afraid that there are no alternatives.