# Upload file to Microsoft OneDrive using graph SDK using asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive using Graph SDK for .Net Core from worker service.
Basically, some files are created at random time and those files needs to be uploaded to specified path on OneDrive from worker service at midnight every day.
I have following information stored in appconfig.json file in application:

- ClientID
- ClientSecret
- TenantID

I have checked samples on various sites but could not find how to upload files using above `ID` and `Secret`. I believe there must but some kind of `authProvider` that I could initialize using above `ID` and `Secret`.

I also checked miscrosoft's documentation but coudl not find any example on how to upload file using SDK with `ID` and `Secret`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online

**Additional Point**

- Upload new file
- Overwrite if file already exists(hope that graph already supports this)
- file size is < 4MB
- path format `/folder1/folder2/filename.pdf`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to assign Application permission (Client credentials flow) to the app registration. See [Application permission to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#application-permission-to-microsoft-graph).

[image]

You can use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider).

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
```

[Upload small file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-updating-an-existing-file) (<4M):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The contents of the file goes here."));

await graphClient.Users[{upn or userID}].Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

If you want to upload large file, see [Upload large files with an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0).

**UPDATE:**

Use `Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -IncludePrerelease` in **Tools** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Console**.

It supports both [uploading a new file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file) and [replacing an existing item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request-to-replace-an-existing-item).

For how to get the items id, please refer to [Get a file or folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

For example, get the item id of `/folder1/folder2` (have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)):

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userID}/drive/root:/folder1:/children`

It will list all the children in folder1, including folder2. Then you can find item id of folder2.

**UPDATE 2:**

Client credentials provider is application identity while all the providers below are user identity.

Since you want to access personal OneDrive (including user identity), you could choose [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider) or [Interactive provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider).

**Authorization code provider**: you need to implement interactively sign-in for your web app and use this provider.

**Interactive provider**: you can easily use this provider to implement  interactively sign-in in a console app.

You can have a quick test with the second provider.

Please note that you should add the Delegated (personal Microsoft account) permissions into the app registration. See [Delegated permission to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#delegated-permission-to-microsoft-graph).

[image]

And in this case, you should modify all `graphClient.Users[{upn or userID}]` to `graphClient.Me` in your code.

I'm afraid that you have to implement sign-in interactively auth flow to access personal OneDrive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Could you please also tell me which nuget packages do I need to use?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Install the [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk)

Comment: Unable to find Microsoft.Graph.Auth NuGet package

Comment: Microsoft.Graph.Auth is still not production ready, what is the alternative?

Comment: Also I do not have `item-id`, I just have a path like `/folder1/folder2/file.pdf`

Comment: @JustAProgrammer See the UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be some misunderstanding. I am not sure if `/folder1/folder2` exists. If it does not exists then I would like to create it.

Comment: @JustAProgrammer See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp.

Comment: I tried to create a file in root directory using `graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);` but I am getting `Tenant does not have a SPO license` error.
I already have office 365 subscription and also registered my app in azure portal but it does not work.

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Did you assign a SPO license (shrepoint online license) to your account? See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159530/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license-when-using-microsoft-graph-api-with-applicati?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Sorry but why do I need SPO license? Does this mean I have to get business license? I have personal subscription od O365

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Because you are trying to upload file to your OneDrive for business. So what you want to do is uploading file to your personal OneDrive?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Have added an **UPDATE 2** in the answer.

Comment: Will this work though? because I am trying to access from worker service? If I user delegate then I have to show authentication dialog to user, isn't it?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer If you use Username/password provider, you don't need to sign in interactively. See the sample I provided in the end. But with this method, you have to hardcode the username and password in your code. And can only upload the file to this user's OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks, I checked your answer but why can't I use tenant ID and secret in persoanl account?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer In fact you can. Whether do use client secret depends on the type of the Azure AD app. If your app is a public client, then the client_secret cannot be included. If the app is a confidential client, then it must be included. The official sample uses public client app, so the client secret is not used here, but tenant id is used.

Comment: Okay, understood your point but then why am I getting `Tenant does not have a SPO license` when I am trying to access personal drive.

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Oh sorry, I made a mistake. For personal OneDrive, ROPC flow is not supported. You have to implement sign-in interactively to access personal OneDrive. See a discussion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327473/microsoft-graph-api-unkownerror?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227180/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-justaprogrammer).

Comment: Okay, understood. So I can not use ID and secret for personal account. So I will have to go with business account of OneDrive.
I'll try the above code with business account and accept the answer if this works.
Thanks!

Comment: @JustAProgrammer For business account (O365 work account), you can follow the steps of "Client credentials provider", which uses Application permission. See the beginning of my answer. Good luck!

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Any updates on this issue?

Comment: How to do that with Graph .NET SDK v5.0, something has been changed, the old way of doing, graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(name).Content.PutAsync, is not working. Any idea how?